# eslint error: Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

I am getting the following error Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body when I run this code.

```
scope.$watch(() => {
            return ngModel.$viewValue;
          }, val => {
            if (ngModel.$isEmpty(val) && ngModel.$dirty) {
              scope.clearInputValue();
              // Remove validation errors
              ngModel.$setValidity('maxnum', true);
              ngModel.$setValidity('minnum', true);
              ngModel.$setValidity('maxsize', true);
              ngModel.$setValidity('minsize', true);
              ngModel.$setValidity('accept', true);
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

A block statement isn't needed in your first function. It is a single expression. If you remove the block statement it should get rid of the warning:

```
scope.$watch(() => ngModel.$viewValue, val => {
            if (ngModel.$isEmpty(val) && ngModel.$dirty) {
              scope.clearInputValue();
              // Remove validation errors
              ngModel.$setValidity('maxnum', true);
              ngModel.$setValidity('minnum', true);
              ngModel.$setValidity('maxsize', true);
              ngModel.$setValidity('minsize', true);
              ngModel.$setValidity('accept', true);
            }
          });
```